# how to generate a random base64 number to power of 11

Tags: php, random, numbers, base64

im trying to work on urls, so i need a random base64 to the power of 11 number, which changes every time you refresh the page.

Im working in php.
any help would be great,
many thanks.

not sure how to go about but maybe somthing like bellow?

```
function toChars($number) {
$res = base_convert($number, 10,26);
$res = strtr($res,'0123456789','qrstuvxwyz');
return $res;
}
```

or

```
$res = ('0123456789','abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvxwyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ');
```

then randomly select from that till you get a 11 digit number aka(base64 to power of 11)

and echo the number here $random_base64_number = ?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? What is a good example of the exact result you are aiming to achieved? http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: Not sure how to go about doing this. But maybe something like this ?              function toChars($number) {
   $res = base_convert($number, 10,26);
   $res = strtr($res,'0123456789','qrstuvxwyz');
   return $res;
}

Comment: Please 'edit' your question to add more content. There is a small edit link under your tags there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont worry figured it out.

```
function base62() {
 $index = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-_';
$res = '';
for ($x = 1; $x <= 11; $x++) {
$res .= $index[rand(1, strlen($index))];
}
echo "The number is: $res <br>";
}
```